# Overloading [] but its result isn't resolving before interacting with other operators (c++)

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, subscript-operator

I've got a data object that I'm trying to get all of the operators working with.  It's one chunk of data with variable ptrs into it, and has any number of different types and sizes and whatnot.  Types are handled with enums and templates and switch statements.  So for each x, d[x] is one type, with any number of them and they can be vectors.  so d[x][y] and d[x][y][z].   I made an internal helper object to help with this. So I have [] overloaded to do things like this, and it'll return the correct type fine: (gcc 4.6.1)

[Edit: I have the same trouble with d(x,y,z)--the problem isn't the [] operator]

```
int i = d[0][3][5];
```

I'm overloading T() in this helper object.

```
template <class T> 
data::helper::operator T ();            // switch(x)...return different types
data::helper data::operator [] (int i); // recurse, return helper(t, d, x, i, j);
```

So I'll just return this object, which resolves it's type at that point (switch with cases tied to t->get< char>(d, x, i, j), etc.).  So the problem is, if I want to do anything like this

```
int i = d[0][1] + d[4][2];
if (d[5][1] != d[3][0]) ...
```

then I ended up having to overload every operator to take in this temporary array helper object.  And now I'm running into having to make a temporary value in there sometimes for some of the operators, which is a pain.

Basically, I feel like I need the operator T() to resolve first, before the compiler tries to take two of these and add them.

I have to do this anyway for the = and +=, etc. operators, but I'd like to delete these jazillion macros helping me define all of these other operators.

Also, I feel like if I could overload the lvalue operator somehow, I could not worry about the = operator.  Maybe that and &() (which right now just returns a templated ptr).  ...?  Or actually, this is more what I mean, at least for d[] = something, but I haven't got this to work.  I'm not sure how to convert a ptr of any type to this return value.

```
data::helper & data::operator [] (int i);
```

I have most of this working but it's a lot of code, and I think I'm going to have to add an extra if statement to every access to do the temp stuff, which I don't want to do.  So what did I miss?

Edit: using d(x,i,j) is the same as d[x][i][j].  I'm pretty sure I'm doing at least the beginning part of what's being used in the link n.m. posted.  The problem is resolving that last helper object into its data before it's used in a statement.  Somehow the compiler wants an operator that accepts the helper object even though it knows how to resolve it when it's alone... I think.  Been a couple days into overloading every operator so I forget all the details. :)

But the main problem now is with stuff like this:

```
helper operator + (helper & l, helper & r)
```

I would like to define the following but it's not getting used--then I think my problems might be solved. similar story for unary ops ~, -, and postfix ++, --.

```
template <class T> T operator + (helper & l, helper & r)
```

But all of this is just because there's something off about my T(), I think.  Most of this is new to me, so I bet I'm missing something.

Comment: [Don't do this](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/matrix-array-of-array.html), [really](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/matrix-c-style-subscript.html).

Comment: I suspect your problem is relatively unrelated to `operator[]`.  Do you have a finite list of types in your `data::helper`, or do you support storing any type in your `data::helper`?  (ie, is this a `boost::variant` or a `boost::any` you have custom crafted and extended?)

Comment: @n.m. Note that the "really" link describes how to make an `operator[][][]` work in a way that works identically (after modest and easy compiler optimization) to how the `(x,y,z)` works.  The problem with `[][][]` is mostly that the naive way to implement it isn't as efficient/safe/etc as the naive way to implement `(x,y,z)`, not that `[][][]` is fundamentally worse.

Comment: @Yakk: *the naive way to implement it isn't as efficient/safe/etc* --- this pretty much does make it fundamentally worse.

Comment: :) I actually speed-tested this with my data(x,i,j) variant and [][][] was slightly faster somehow. heh.  
at the moment, it's a finite list of types but easily extendable.  honestly, I'm not sure which boost:: it is. lol though man, so often i wish i just used boost.  learning exercise, i guess.

Comment: I have this problem regardless of whether I use d[][][] or d(x,i,j). I bet I'm doing [][][] naively :) The types are like char, uchar, int, etc. float, bits_8, _16, vectors of all of those, etc.  so pretty much all basic types in C plus some stuff meant for use with bitwise ops only.  Also the type is stored in the data, the helper uses its methods to figure stuff out.  part of this is to convert user defined enums, from d[enum] to d[x][i].  But I use templates heavily for return values and setting values, etc.  I just switch out my type ID system with C types as template parameters.

Comment: @Yakk I think it's boost::variant.  i had planned on allowing custom data types but I haven't tried to implement it yet.  It may not be important/worth it.

Comment: @n.m. I don't judge design by assuming someone will implement it naively. Once we know the right way, and if we can figure out a way to make implementing it that way *easy*, it goes from a "gotcha" to a design pattern. Expression trees, including returning intermediate objects for `[]`, are a known design pattern, and one that starship will have to be using in order to get something like what is described working *anyhow*.

Comment: A way I'd approach this would be to keep track of what operators work on what types.  Then, replace your `helper` class with a `template` that lists the types it supports, like `boost::variant`.  `helper<...> + helper<...>` now returns an expression object that knows which types (in theory) it could produce (ie, it is another `helper<...>`, but with a different set of types)... or a pure expression object.  Only when it is assigned to a real value does the entire expression collapse.  This isn't easy, but what you are doing isn't for the faint of heart either.

Comment: btw, [][][] is faster at the moment probably because T() isn't getting called.  I'm resolving that stuff within =, +=, etc., etc.  I'm not entirely sure it's always faster but whatever I tested, it sure was, to my surprise. :)  Oops, I probably didn't highlight that.  It can't figure out what to do when it's like T() + T() for two d[], so d[][] + d[][].  so I overload + and work on the data directly.  but with that same example, now I have to make a temporary templated variable and check if i need to use it every time, I think.

Comment: @Yakk Oh, it actually works fine for any type and any operators except for this one class of stuff where I need to return a helper, "helper operator + (helper & l, helper & r)".  It feels really clumsy to me because I have to overload everything instead of having that T() work the way I want it to, though it is fast, so honestly, oh well.  :)  But I still want it for that one class of ops I mentioned.

Comment: what I really want to do is define this:  template <class T> T operator + (helper & l, helper & r).  The compiler never sees it though.  It doesn't list it when listing possib alternatives.  possibly because it's conflicting with other  operator + (helper, T), operator + (T, helper).

Comment: @n.m. actually, i am doing all of what's on that link, except the const stuff.

Comment: BTW, all of this method of access is for one use of this which is not speed critical.  it's like the user interface to the data, and then i'll be evolving that data.  and it'll make a few things easier.  but for the intensive stuff where I crawl through the data, I definitely don't use [][] or (x,i).  I use more direct methods, the methods used by [][].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The practical way to do this kind of thing is with expression templates.

I'd change your return values from `operator[]` to an expression template even.

This will use C++11 features, because it makes it shorter.

```
enum class ExpressionType { Index, Addition };
template< ExpressionType Op, typename LHS, typename RHS >
struct Expression {
  LHS lhs;
  RHS rhs;
  template<typename T>
  operator T();
};
// to separate out the evaluation code:
template< typename T, ExpressionType Op, typename LHS, typename RHS >
struct Evaluate {
  T operator()( Expression<Op, LHS, RHS> exp ) const;
};
template< ExpressionType Op, typename LHS, typename RHS >
template<typename T>
Expression<Op,LHS,RHS>::operator T() {
  return Evaluate<T,Op,LHS,RHS>()( std::move(*this) );
}
// further specializations needed:
template< typename T, typename RHS >
struct Evaluate< T, ExpressionType::Index, data, RHS > {
  T operator()( Expression<Op, ExpressionType::Index, data, RHS> exp ) const {
    // we just assume RHS can be treated like an integer.  If it cannot,
    // we fail to compile.  We can improve this with SFINAE elsewhere...
    return exp.lhs.get_nth(exp.rhs);
  }
};
template< typename T, typename LHS, typename RHS >
struct Evaluate< T, ExpressionType::Addition, LHS, RHS > {
  T operator()( Expression<Op, ExpressionType::Index, data, RHS> exp ) const {
    // code with all of LHS, RHS and T visible!
  }
};
template<typename E>
struct is_expression : std::false_type {};
template<ExpressionType Op, typename LHS, typename RHS>
struct is_expression<Expression<Op,LHS,RHS> : std::true_type {};
template<ExpressionType Op, typename LHS, typename RHS>
Expression<Op, LHS, RHS> make_expression( LHS&& lhs, RHS&& rhs ) {
  return { std::forward<LHS>(lhs), std::forward<RHS>(rhs) };
}
// here is why I want to start out with returning an expression.  This SFINAE test
// is extremely easy because of that -- we overload operator+ on any two types, so long
// as one of them is an Expression!
template<typename LHS, typename RHS, typename=typename std::enable_if<is_expression<LHS>::value || is_expression<RHS>::value >::type>
ExpressionType<ExpressionType::Addition, LHS, RHS> operator+( LHS&& lhs, RHS&& rhs )
{
  return make_expression<ExpressionType::Addition>(std::forward<LHS>(lhs), std::forward<RHS>(rhs) );
}
```

so the idea is, we build at compile time a tree of templates that represent the order in which various expressions are evaluated by the compiler.

When we finally cast it to a concrete type `T`, only then do we start the evaluation work.

This avoids having to create any temporaries, but does mean we have to do a lot of template mojo in order to get things up and running.  The above is a sketch of such an template expression tree generator.

To see a complete implementation of a simple case, here is a link to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_templates)'s article on the subject, where a full blown expression tree system is built up to do `std::vector` vector processing without temporaries.

Comment: OK, this is good stuff.  I just learned how to do CRTP.  I'm not convinced that I need this though.  Reading up on it, it seems like it's used for several reasons that I am not worried about.  Not that what I'm doing now is *less* complicated :)  Is there a reason why I can't have the expression evaluate in something like this:  int i = d(0,0) + d(1,1)?  And does this method actually compile down to be faster than the temp object?  I'm unsure if that object ever actually exists.  And again, I'm confused why I am being forced to have a helper operator + (helper l, helper r).

Comment: and, i'm fairly out of it, i gotta drink some coffee and/or sleep and read through this code and link more.  :)  again, crtp in my toolset just last week, and I'm using it for the distance crawler, by far the most intensive use of this data most likely, and then the user can define other crawlers.  I might use this temp object [] stuff for mutations just to simplify things, and then for the user to interact with data, but I have direct access methods that should be used anyway when the type is known.  This is just to make it super simple, if the user so desires.  but i'm gonna read this code.

Comment: Reading through this, hmm, but also could I do something like this with the types?  I have an enum list of types.  I had originally hoped to do something like be able to make templated objects, passing in a list of enums, so that it would somehow compile in tighter than it would by generating the list of types and such after the program is running. as near as I can tell, the real overhead is my switching on enum types as I access different d[x][..], just the x.  So my crawlers do all for each x, then no problem. But is that something I could get rid of with something analogous to this?

Comment: I just realized that my basic problem is for some reason I got fixated on the idea of needing:  helper operation + (helper l, helper r), when all I need is:  double operation + (helper l, helper r). I got a couple hours into a new temp object just for those cases when I realized this. :) @Yakk thanks for your help!  I really appreciate it.  I think some day I may refactor this with variadic templates and expression templates. But both of those are fairly confusing to me at this point. :) What you wrote looks very powerful and concise.

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer.  My basic problems had to do with being new to this and not understanding exactly what T() was doing.  I am switching out types within T() and forgot that then T() is called for some other type.  I was thinking I was forcing that type return but all I'm doing is making the type conversion valid.  So expression templates are probably necessary to avoid doing what I did to quickly fix this, just making ops that only deal with this temp data object (eg. d[] + d[]) use a double or long for bitwise stuff. That is not ideal, so I will eventually be implementing this.

Comment: also, looked at boost a bunch last night, and this is not a boost::variant :)